# How to use Primary Key In a Serializer in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

My Model is

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    mobile_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
```

and serialzer is :

```
class UserInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserInfo
        fields = ('mobile_no','user')
```

but whenever I tried to use this

```
serializer = UserInfoSerializer(data=data)
if serializer.is_valid():
   serializer.save()
```

It is not saving the data and giving errors.

Is there any method to use other then this to for using Primary key.

Comment: can you tell me what error message it throwing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [PrimaryKeyRelatedField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield)

add this to your serializer

```
user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all())
```

Your `UserInfoSerializer` should look like:

```
class UserInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = UserInfo
        fields = ('mobile_no','user')
```

**Update**
If you want to update existing object in database then you have to pass `model instance` as an argument to `UserInfoSerializer` constructor.

```
user_info = self.get_object()
serializer = UserInfoSerializer(user_info, data=data)
```

Comment: I am able to create now. But when I am going to update the data using user_serializer.save(),It is save without giving error but Not able to reflect it on database.