# NOT NULL constraint when creating a new user in django

Tags: python, django

I created a Django API to create a new user. However, when I try to create a user I get the error message:

`IntegrityError at /api/v1/users/register/ NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_user.user_id`

This is what I have in models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class User(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150)
    signup_confirmation = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_profile_signal(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        User.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
```

In serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import User

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('user_id', 'name', 'location', 'password', 'email', 'signup_confirmation')
```

and my views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from .models import User
from rest_framework.decorators import action


from .forms import SignUpForm
from .tokens import account_activation_token

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('name')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    @action (detail=True, methods=['post'])
    def register(self, request):
        print(request)
```

Any ideas on what I can do to resolve this error

Comment: I think it's because you're including `user_id` in the serializer.  Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37858012/494134

Answer (score 0):

As John wrote in a comment:
Here you have a problem:  `fields = ('user_id',...)`.

I also advise you to change your `User` model. If you don't need separating (I suppose you don't), it is way better to create your `User` with inheritance directly from `AbstractUser` instead of creating in fact doubled `User` models.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    ...
```

In this way you will already have `username`, `password` and `email`, but you can add anything else in same model, instead of using `user.user` etc.

Comment: So doing this gives me the error:

ERRORS:
accounts.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'accounts.User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'auth.User.groups'.

Comment: Oh, yeah. You need to add `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_app.User'` to your settings.py. You will not regret that in the future. For more info check i.e. https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-custom-user-model